# How to create a helper column according to a rule in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a dropdown that obeys a rule, for example i have a table that contains 50  lines with value of Travel 01, Travel 02, travel 03, etc, i created a data validation rule with that range but when the user will choose it appears all 50 lines and 50 is just an example, it will be more in the real spreadsheet, what i want to do is a rule where if previous trip was chosen travel 35, then the dropdown should only show options 34, 35, 36, which is previous trip number, current trip number and one more for the next trip, i know i need a helper table but i am not being able to think a way that this can be done, any thoughts?

I have a spreadsheet to use as example
[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=1537723575)

Tried to create a helper column but with no success.

Comment: Can you explain the problem better? It is still now clear what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
=LAMBDA(z,FILTER(A:A,XMATCH(ROW(A:A),{1,z-1,z,z+1})))((XMATCH("Current Trip",B:B)))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Cheers, but in your formula you used match "Current Trip" which it was inserted as an example, my question would be how to have a formula for that value too, only then your formula would work, the Last Trip value should change in the column according to the last trip chosen, makes sense?

Comment: You mean like if I select the drop-down as let's say Travel 05, then the drop-down should auto re-configure itself to show just the 3 values of Travel 04, 05, 06?!